# query nearby places with latitude and longitude in new places sdk for android

Tags: android, google-places-api, geocoding, google-places

As there is the announcement of depreciation of Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android, we have a new version of the Places SDK for Android is now available. It's recommended updating to the new version as soon as possible.

Source: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Now, I am updated to the new version `com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0` but the problem is I want to get nearby places for collection of coordinates (latitude and longitude), not by the user's current location(lat, long).

The official documentation suggests that we should use fetchPlace where we need to pass PLACE_ID but since I don't have PLACE_ID, I only have the collection of locations(latitude & longitude) so

```
// Define a Place ID. <== I don't have Place ID, how to get it with coordinates(lat,long)
String placeId = "INSERT_PLACE_ID_HERE";

// Specify the fields to return.
List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, 
Place.Field.NAME);

// Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array.
FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(placeId, placeFields)
    .build();

// Add a listener to handle the response.
  placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
  Place place = response.getPlace();
  Log.i(TAG, "Place found: " + place.getName());
}).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
  if(exception instanceof ApiException) {
    ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
    int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
    // Handle error with given status code.
    Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());
   }
});
```

**How I can get nearby(likelihood) places by passing latitude and longitude using this new version of Places SDK?**

Note: I don't want to use REST calls to Places API for place id

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse generic reverse geocoding returns placeid in json, is this not what you want? ideally you'd get the placeid when you get a lat long and cache it, refreshing placeid information is free in google maps api